# Prestashop - change product order in category fails

Tags: prestashop-1.6

In prestashop 1.6.1.4 I cannot change the order of products in category,
when I change in the admin (Products Catalog > Filter by category) it doesn't save to the DB.

After reload of the admin page the position numbers have wrong values, instead of 1...N it shows 0,0,0,3,4,5...

Answer (score 0):

In classes/Product.php, change updatePosition to:

```
public function updatePosition($way, $position)
{
    $sql = '
        SELECT cp.`id_product`, cp.`position`, cp.`id_category`
        FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product` cp
        WHERE cp.`id_category` = ' . (int)Tools::getValue('id_category', 1) . '
        ORDER BY cp.`position` ASC';
    if (!$res = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql
    )) {

        return false;
    }

    $loop_position = -1;
    foreach ($res as $product) {
            $loop_position++;
            $product['position'] = $loop_position;
            $sql3 = '
        UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product`
        SET `position` = ' . (int)$loop_position . '
        WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int)$product['id_product'] . '
        AND `id_category`=' . (int)$product['id_category'];
            Db::getInstance()->execute($sql3);
        $loop_position = $product['position'];

        if ((int)$product['id_product'] == (int)$this->id) {

            $moved_product = $product;
        }
    }
    if (!isset($moved_product) || !isset($position))
        return false;

    // < and > statements rather than BETWEEN operator
    // since BETWEEN is treated differently according to databases
    $sql2 = '
        UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product`
        SET `position`= `position` ' . ($way ? '- 1' : '+ 1') . '
        WHERE `position`
        ' . ($way
            ? '> ' . (int)$moved_product['position'] . ' AND `position` <= ' . (int)$position
            : '< ' . (int)$moved_product['position'] . ' AND `position` >= ' . (int)$position) . '
        AND `id_category`=' . (int)$moved_product['id_category'];
    $sql3 = '
        UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_product`
        SET `position` = ' . (int)$position . '
        WHERE `id_product` = ' . (int)$moved_product['id_product'] . '
        AND `id_category`=' . (int)$moved_product['id_category'];
    return (Db::getInstance()->execute($sql2)
    && Db::getInstance()->execute($sql3));
}
```